# ¿Por que inserta solo el 1 en lugar de todos los elementos de la lista?

Tags: python, lista, insert

Buen día a todos. Quisiera que, si es posible, me ayuden a comprender este código. No comprendo por qué solo agrega en la posición 1 el numero 1 en lugar de todos los elementos de la lista. Creí que imprimiría [1, 3, 2, 1 ,2, 3]. Cambié el numero de la posición a insertar a 0
insert(0, lista[x]), pero sigue imprimiendo solo el 1.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
for x in range(len(lista)):
  lista.insert(1, lista[x])
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las herramientas de depuración más importante es `print()`. Con ella podemos interrogar el contenido de variables y ver su evolución a lo largo del tiempo.

Por ejemplo, insertare unos `print()` para ver como evoluciona la lista en cada iteración:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
print(lista)
for x in range(len(lista)):
  lista.insert(1, lista[x])
  print(lista)
```

resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

En la primera iteración tienes `[1, 2, 3]`, sacas el elemento `x = 0`, que vale 1, y lo insertas en la posición 1, lo que deja

```
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

En la siguiente pasada tomas el elemento `x = 1`, que también vale 1, y lo insertas nuevamente en la posición 1, lo que deja

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

En resumen: siempre estas insertando en la posición 1 el elemento que extraes de la última posición llenada, que siempres llenas con 1.

**Solución**

Se puede construir una nueva lista con la siguiente expresión

```
lista = [lista[0], *lista, *lista[1:]]
```

Creamos una nueva lista tomando el primer elemento, todos los elementos y luego los elementos después del primero: La forma `*lista` toma la lista y la desempaqueta. Donde dice `*lista` es equivalente a `1, 2, 3`.

Comment: Ya entiendo! Se va creando una nueva lista, con mas elementos, por eso siempre se repite el 1 y a su vez se va agregando hasta completar el ciclo for. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!